# Why is pagination with a fraction in owl-carousel not immediately displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

For some reason, pagination with a fraction is not displayed immediately, but only when the slider turns to the next slide or if you do it yourself. What is the reason?

Site http://ilyin1ib.beget.tech/
Code https://jsfiddle.net/ve4oaq1L/

```js
$('.spaces-gal').on('initialized.owl.carousel changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
        if (!e.namespace)  {
          return;
        }
        var carousel = e.relatedTarget;
        $('.slider-counter').text(carousel.relative(carousel.current()) + 1 + '/' + carousel.items().length);
      }).owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        loop:true,
        margin:0,
        nav:true
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spaces-gal owl-carousel">
                    <div class="spaces-slide one">
                        <h4>Private Space</h4>
                        <p>Comfortable space, Full speed wifi, Free coffe & Snack<br>and many more</p>
                        <div class="details">
                            <span>Check avaibility</span><i class='fas fa-chevron-right'></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="spaces-slide two">
                        <img src="img/space-2.jpg" alt="2">
                        <span>Custom Office</span>
                        <div class="details">
                            <span>Check avaibility</span><i class='fas fa-chevron-right'></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="spaces-slide three">
                        <img src="img/space-3.jpg" alt="3">
                        <div class="details">
                            <span>Check avaibility</span><i class='fas fa-chevron-right'></i>
                        </div>
                        <span>Problem solving</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="spaces-slide four">
                        <img src="img/space-4.jpg" alt="4">
                        <div class="details">
                            <span>Check avaibility</span><i class='fas fa-chevron-right'></i>
                        </div>
                        <span>Working with team</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: code snippet needs the owl carousel link as an external resource....

Comment: and how to do it?